# My slider only shows 1st and 3rd slider but not the 2nd and 4th slider for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I made a simple slider which works fine for normal table, but when I try to use that slider for my customised bootstrap table only 1st, 3rd slider is showing up but not the 2nd and 4th.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
console.log("len "+x.length);
if (n > x.length) {

  slideIndex = 1;
}    
if (n < 1) {
   slideIndex = x.length;
 }
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 }
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <div class="mySlides">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4 class="m-b-30 m-t-0">Q'3</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                            <th>Time Period</th>
                                            <th>Jan</th>
                                            <th>Feb</th>
                                            <th>Mar</th>
                                            <th>Total</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td># of Project<br>Completed</td>
                                            <td>20</td>                                                                </td>
                                            <td>17</td>
                                            <td>15</td>
                                            <td>52</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Total <br>Phases</td>
                                            <td>14</td>
                                            <td>29</td>
                                            <td>23</td>
                                            <td>74</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td># Feedback <br>Received</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>7</td>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>21</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Adiva <br>Incurred (hrs)</td>
                                            <td>927</td>
                                            <td>965</td>
                                            <td>636</td>
                                            <td>2528</td>
                                        </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

 <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" 
 onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" 
   onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
```

I have given only the one input file. More 3 similar table will be added, But after adding this to my class, only 1st and 3rd one is showing. Another object like image, normal text sliding is working fine, but only this table shows the problem. And I am using only core *JS* for sliding, but my main file has *jquery*, but there are for another purposes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayphi/xo66cgxf/ - works fine for me if `plusDivs()` is available in global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve figured it out. It was a div tag problem. Div wasnt closed properly. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have wrong html markup. There is one superfluous `</td>` which broke valid html.